# SharePoint view in grouping items by the first letter of the Title field

Tags: list-view, groups, grouping

I followed [this article](http://sharepointlive.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-build-sharepoint-view-in.html) and it works fine if the number of items for a letter is less than 30.

But it fails when you have more than 30 items and go back and forth for a group. Say Under "S" you have 70 items (and it set to show 30 items per page), then when you click on next the grouping still fine. However, when you go back to 1-30 (the first page) all items starts with "A" shows up under "S". {may there is a bug in SharePoint 2010?}

Comment: Does applying sorting to the title field help with the issue?

Comment: I tried that too but no.

Comment: How many items will there (eventually) be in the list?

Comment: In T I have 230 items, in P I have 23 items, they vary. the list will grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is a known issue, and a patch was released:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b30a9bc6-71ad-4558-a0ab-6c621c2e3330/

If you're looking for a workaround, instead of grouping you could use connected Web Parts and filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Is the item limit for the view set to 30 to display as batches? I believe if the item display limit is increased to the maximum,the pagination within the groups will be removed and then everything should work fine.

**EDIT:**  As I suggested in my comment, Subgrouping a different column would be a better option. You can first select a column which is more meaningful to group (For eg. Created By) and then subgroup them with Initials, or viceversa. It would look something similar to this post - https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Nested-Grouping-in-SharePoint-Views.aspx

Comment: Actually, I am already using this method (as a temporary solution). Remember the DocLib is growing rapidly so eventually I need to set the limit.

Comment: How about trying a nested grouping for initials then? Create one more column called 'Sub Initial' with formula =UPPER(LEFT(Title,2)). Then Group by Initial and then Sub Initial. This will give you grouping of A to Z and within A you would have AA to AZ which reduces the possibility of paging also. I think this should be implemented in your case since the list is growing rapidly.

Comment: I don't know if user will like sub grouping but something to consider. I used =IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(Title,1))),"0",UPPER(LEFT(Title,1))) to accommodate numbers as well.

Comment: Anyone knows why LinkFilename is not listed for Calculated Column?

Comment: I don't think LinkFilename is a supported type for calculated columns.

Comment: With the potentially large number of items and the usability issues around grouping - would using a connected Text Filter Web Part or a Search Results web part (only searching on the given field) help the users out more?

Comment: @Mary: usually the fields that can be used for calculations are "stable" fields (text, number, choice). Fields that include an external reference (lookup, link) can't, maybe the reason is that they could break if the site is modified...